# Dealing with small variations in CSS?

Tags: css, architecture

Whats the best way of dealing with small variations in CSS?

For instance say if I have two buttons:

.btn-red .btn-blue

And I want each of the buttons next to one another but I want .btn-blue to have margin-left of 10 pixels.

I have a number of options that I could implement:

- I could add an inline style to the .btn-blue element (but then you have issues of maintainability and readability if your conforming to a naming convention like BEM).
- I could create a utility class that adds 10 pixels of margin (but then I'm falling into the trap of potentially having many one off utility classes, how about if I want an additional 20 pixels of margin on another item?)
- I could extend .btn-blue and apply a different class (but that creates near enough the same problems as having a one-off utility class)
- I could add 10 pixels directly to the .btn-green class but that conflicts with the Single Responsibility Principle.
- I could target a wrapper class and using a descendent selector target .btn-blue but then I negate the usefulness of using something like BEM and fall into the world of specificity.

I realise the questions rather pedantic but this is one of the key issues as my CSS files grow that typically spirals out of control.

Say if I had the following...

SASS:

```
.btn {
  padding: 10px  30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
}

.btn-red,
.btn-blue {
  @extend .btn;
  color: white;
}

.btn-red {
  background: red;
}

.btn-blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-wrap">
  <button class="btn-red">
    Mr Red
  </button>
  <button class="btn-blue">
    Mr Blue
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: without any code/snippet showing your structure and issue , answering will be guessing :)

Comment: added an example, no need to guess :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am honestly not quite certain about what you're trying to achieve, but could something like this help?

```
.btn-red + .btn-blue { /* Or [class*="btn-"] + [class*="btn-"], maybe */
   margin-left: 10px;
}
```